Uncertainty in current mode operation of detector
I have come across an equation while reading Knoll's book $$ \frac{\sigma_I}{I_0}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{\sqrt{rT}}{n} $$
In the same I encountered another equation $ I_0 =rQ = r \frac{E}{W} q $
$$ \begin{align}
\sigma_I  & = \text{Uncertainty in measurement} \\
n & = \text{Number of detected charged particle} \\
r & = \text{Rate of event} \\
T & = \text{Response time of the detector} \\
W & = \text{Average energy needed to create one electron hole pair}
\end{align}$$
Comparing both equations $I_0$ does not comply with both the equations.
How both equations can be explained, or I am missing something.

Why you think $I_0$ does not comply with both the equations ? Can you explain your confusion in more details ?

$ \frac{E}{W} = n$ and $I_0 = rnq$  so how it can be directly written as n in the first equation

$$\frac{\sigma_I}{I_0}=\frac{rq\sqrt n}{rq~n}
\tag a$$
Numerator is standard deviation of current, $\sqrt n$ comes from Poisson statistics. $n=t/T=ft$,- number of events definition from knowing their frequency and time domain.
Your first given expression is what is left after eliminating $rq$ part in numerator and denominator in (a) eq.
HTH!
